# Excel Run-time error '13': Type mismatch code

Tags: vba, excel

I am not able to get this error fixed, its just some excel document I am playing around with:

This is in the Sheet1(OrderInvoice):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  Set rng = Sheets("CustomerList").Range("A2:A5")

  'Sheets("CustomerList").Range("A2:A5").Value

  'For Each cell In rng

  'If cell = Range("C10").Value Then
  If Sheets("CustomerList").Range("A2:A5") = Range("C10").Value Then
  Sheets("OrderInvoice").Range("C11").Value = Sheets("CustomerList").Range(1, 2).Value
  Sheets("OrderInvoice").Range("I11").Value = Sheets("CustomerList").Range(1, 4).Value
  Sheets("OrderInvoice").Range("C12").Value = Sheets("CustomerList").Range(1, 3).Value
  End If

  'Next cell

  'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Sheets("CustomerList").Range("A2:A5") = Range("C10").Value Then` is comparing a `Variant()` (on the left) with a `Variant` on the right.  You can't test equity of an array.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Depends on what the comparison is supposed to be checking.

Comment: It's checking the items in the Customer List sheet and comparing it to something in a combo box

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/vdj359ymf/  - Customer List

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/6uxu5mret/ - Form Layout

Comment: This task is better suited for a `VLookup` formula.

Comment: Okay so instead of that line I replace it with a VLookup

Comment: I mean you write `VLookup` formulas in the cells you want to fill in your `OrderInvoice` worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas are:

For `Cust Name`:

```
=VLookup(C10, 'CustomerList'!A:D, 2, false)
```

For `Company`:

```
=VLookup(C10, 'CustomerList'!A:D, 3, false)
```

For `Contact Number`:

```
=VLookup(C10, 'CustomerList'!A:D, 4, false)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this

Comment: Yes, I have the Vlookup running, now I am encountering some other issues @A.S.H

Comment: It seems to be newer issues, but I will address that seperately

Answer (score 0):

you could be better off with `Find()` method of `Range` object

```
Dim rng As Range

With Sheets("CustomerList") '<--| reference "CustomerList" sheet
    With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A range from row 2 down to last not empty one
        Set rng = .Find(what:=Range("C10").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| search referenced range for "Cust Num" entry
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
            Range("C11").Value = rng.Offset(, 1).Value '<--| fill cell C11 with value in cell 1 column offset the found CustNum
            Range("C12").Value = rng.Offset(, 2).Value '<--| fill cell C12 with value in cell 2 columns offset the found CustNum
            Range("I11").Value = rng.Offset(, 3).Value '<--| fill cell I11 with value in cell 3 columns offset the found CustNum
        End If
    End With
End With
```

---

Furthermore, from your screen shots I got that your are trying to manage user's entries in the "Form" sheet.

In this case I'd wrote such a `Worksheet_Change()` event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "C10" '<--| user edited "Cust Num" entry
            FillCustomerInfo Target.Value '<--| call the sub responsible for handling "Customer Number" entry
        Case "C6" '<--| user edited "Order Number" entry
            FillOrderNumberInfo Target.Value '<--| call the sub responsible for handling "Order Number" entry
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

where you check which cell has been changed by the user and launch corresponding sub to treat that cell content accordingly

in this case, `FillCustomerInfo()` Sub would therefore be:

```
Sub FillCustomerInfo(val As Variant)
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("CustomerList") '<--| reference "CustomerList" sheet
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A range from row 2 down to last not empty one
            Set rng = .Find(what:=val, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| search referenced range for passed value
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
                Range("C11").Value = rng.Offset(, 1).Value '<--| fill cell C11 with value in cell 1 column offset the found CustNum
                Range("C12").Value = rng.Offset(, 2).Value '<--| fill cell C12 with value in cell 2 columns offset the found CustNum
                Range("I11").Value = rng.Offset(, 3).Value '<--| fill cell I11 with value in cell 3 columns offset the found CustNum
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mikha'ilHathey, did you get through it?